Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Boot to Black Screen with Cursor Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen 12
I love my Ubuntu laptop, but I powered it down one day, and when I turned it back on I was met with just a black screen with a cursor visible in the bottom right part of the screen. It does not respond to any key inputs.
I read on Ubuntu 20.04 boots to black screen with flashing cursor that I should be trying to use the CLI, but I have no way of doing anything except going into bios. I ran Lenovo diagnostics, and it passed every test. I also read online that I could try a bootable USB to access my files and copy them to another USB to save them if I needed to reinstall the OS later. That did not work either due to permission issues.
After many frustrated attempts and nothing working, I installed Ubuntu on another partition of the drive. After doing this I referred to Ubuntu 22.04 boots to a black screen with a visible cursor, where I edited /etc/gdm3/custom.conf of my original partition with no luck. When I try and boot into it again, I am met with some glitchy login screen where I can just see my profile pic. From there I tried all combinations of CTRL+Shift+F# keys with no change except a few flickers of the screen.
I am truly at a loss for what to do. I spent a lot of time configuring my profile to be exactly how I wanted it. Now, I can see all my work sitting there without being able to use it. I do not like the GUI of Ubuntu 22.04.1 installation, and I would just like to get my old profile back.
I am open to trying anything to get my previous installation to work. I am a student, and a lot of my profiles for school work are still on there. I would prefer not to move everything over and start from there, because I miss the old GUI.
UPDATE:
After booting and selecting Advanced options for Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS (on /dev/nvme0n1p3) and selecting: Ubuntu, with Linux 6.8.0-47-generic, I was able to use my laptop normally, but selecting Ubuntu, with Linux 6.8.0-47-generic results in a black screen.
Can someone please help me make this happen automatically so I do not have to navigate to that every time I want to use my laptop? I would also appreciate instructions on how to remove the recently installed Ubuntu partition safely.

Did you try 24.04? Usually, later versions of Ubuntu have better support for recent hardware.

select default boot entry -> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Configuring_GRUB_2
